# How to dynamically generate a concatenated URL based on filtered table results in Looker Studio?

Tags: concatenation, looker-studio, dynamic-url

I'm working with Google Data Studio to create a report that functions as a search engine for users to find the best cars to sell to their customers. The report includes a table with a column for car IDs and several filters (price, model, etc.) to refine the search.

The challenge I'm facing is with our multi car ID generator. We need to create a dynamic link that starts with a base URL (e.g., "https://www.x.com/app/merchant/cars?ID=") and appends car IDs separated by "%2C". For instance, the link should look like "https://www.x.com/nl/app/cars?ID=KM17468%2CYA89113%2CFS59256%2C" after the IDs are selected.

I want to generate this URL in the report based on the car IDs that appear in the table after the filters are applied. Ideally, the URL should update dynamically as the filters change.

**What I've tried:**

- I've considered creating a calculated field to concatenate the IDs, but Google Data Studio doesn't seem to support aggregation of multiple row values into a single URL directly.
- I've looked into using Google Sheets as an intermediary to construct the URL, but I'm concerned about concurrency issues with multiple users applying different filters.

**My question:**
Is there a way to dynamically generate a multi-ID URL in Looker Studio that reflects the current filtered state of a table, suitable for multiple concurrent users? If so, how can this be achieved? Are there any best practices or workarounds that would allow me to create such a link without running into concurrency issues?

Thanks in advance.